# error while attaching file in sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-designer

When trying to attach file in share point site, getting error `'null or not an object'` in `init.js`. Also the page is not scrolled till end and a part of page is left behind.

Comment: Do you have any custom JavaScript on that page?

Comment: Yes , i do a have custom jQuery file

Comment: Is it possible to include the content of the file in your question?

Comment: It occurs in any site/page created in sharepoint whenever try to attach file, even if custom jQuery is not included

Comment: Debug the javascript with the developer tools of IE. Looks like there is some js that errors out and then upsets the native SharePoint js.